# python web scraping _images scraping

Tags: web, web-scraping

I faced problem as shown in attached photos when i used this code the images showed like this “ not appear “

```
    from email.mime import image
    import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import os

  url = 'https://www.imdb.com/search/title/?groups=top_100&sort=user_rating,desc&count=100&start=%22+%22&ref_=adv_nxt'
r = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

images = soup.find_all('img')

for image in images:
   name = image['alt']
   link = image ['src']
   with open (name + '.jpg','wb') as f:
       im = requests.get(link)
       f.write(im.content)
```

Comment: We need more info, post your code. You just said this code? Which code is it?

Comment: The code that in the image

Comment: Format code, including indentation.